# How can I remove duplicates in an array but keep the same order?

Tags: list, matlab, arrays, duplicates

I have this cell array in MATLAB:

```
y = { 'd' 'f' 'a' 'g' 'g' 'a' 'w' 'h'}
```

I use `unique(y)` to get rid of the duplicates but it rearranges the strings in alphabetical order:

```
>> unique(y)

ans =

'a'    'd'    'f'    'g'    'h'    'w'
```

I want to remove the duplicates but keep the same order. I know I could write a function do do this but was wondering if there was a simpler way using `unique` to remove duplicates while keeping the same order just with the duplicates removed.

I want it to return this:

```
>> unique(y)

ans = 

'd'    'f'    'a'    'g'    'w'    'h'
```

Comment: I suppose the answer given by Amro is the best way to achieve this now. `unique(y, 'stable')`

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Here's one solution that uses some additional input and output arguments that [UNIQUE](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/unique.html) has:

```
>> y = { 'd' 'f' 'a' 'g' 'g' 'a' 'w' 'h'};  %# Sample data
>> [~,index] = unique(y,'first');        %# Capture the index, ignore the actual values
>> y(sort(index))                           %# Index y with the sorted index

ans = 

    'd'    'f'    'a'    'g'    'w'    'h'
```

Comment: Now why didn't I think of doing it this way? +1

Comment: +1: I already have a function in my path called `uniq.m` that does this exactly, I use it all the time :)

Answer (score 21):

In MATLAB R2012a, a new [order flag](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/unique.html#inputarg_setOrder) was added:

```
>> y = {'d' 'f' 'a' 'g' 'g' 'a' 'w' 'h'};
>> unique(y, 'stable')
ans = 
    'd'    'f'    'a'    'g'    'w'    'h'
```

Answer (score 6):

If you look at the documentation for [`unique`](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/unique.html), there's the option to return an index along with the sorted array. You can specify whether you want the first or last occurrence of a number to be returned to the index as well.

For example:

```
a=[5, 3, 4, 2, 1, 5, 4];

[b,order]=unique(a,'first')
```

returns

`b=[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]` and `m=[5, 4, 2, 3, 1]`

You can sort your order array and store the index next

```
[~,index]=sort(order) %# use a throw-away variable instead of ~ for older versions
```

and finally re-index b

```
b=b(index)
```