# How to remove duplicate rows from matrix

Tags: arrays, matlab, matrix, duplicates

I want to remove duplicate rows from a matrix.  I read [How can I remove duplicates in an array but keep the same order?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3065387/how-can-i-remove-duplicates-in-an-array-but-keep-the-same-order), but this is not exactly what I want.

The solution above removes duplicate values (cells) from matrix (and returns a vector), but I need to remove duplicate **rows** and return a matrix — the same matrix without duplicate rows.

Example:

```
a = [1,2; 3,4; 5,6; 1,2; 7,8]

a =
     1     2
     3     4
     5     6
     1     2
     7     8

%...

ans =
     1     2
     3     4
     5     6
     7     8
```

The order doesn't matter.

Comment: if you also want to keep the original order of the rows, check out this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7781749/junk-index-and-unique-on-a-matrix-how-to-keep-matrix-format/7782227#7782227

Answer (score 14, accepted):

See http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/unique.html

> b = unique(A, 'rows') returns the unique rows of A.

Comment: Does anyone know the algorithm used to compute that function?

Comment: @Will , just sort. http://blogs.mathworks.com/loren/2009/11/26/unique-values-without-rearrangement/#1

Answer (score -1):

Here is my solution

```
package com.test;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.Set;

public class DuplicateInMatrix {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Integer[][] arr = { { 1, 2, 3 }, { 4, 5, 6 }, { 1, 2, 3 } };
        Set<Element> set = new HashSet<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            set.add(new Element(arr.length, arr[i]));
        }

        buildResultArray(set);
    }

    private static void buildResultArray(Set<Element> set) {
        Integer[][] arr = new Integer[set.size()][];
        Iterator<Element> itr = set.iterator();
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length && itr.hasNext(); i++) {
            arr[i] = itr.next().row;
        }
        printArrray(arr);
    }

    private static void printArrray(Integer[][] arr) {

        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < arr[i].length; j++) {
                System.out.print(arr[i][j] + " ");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }

    static class Element {
        int n;
        Integer[] row = new Integer[n];

        public Element(int n, Integer[] row) {
            this.n = n;
            this.row = row;
        }

        @Override
        public int hashCode() {
            return Arrays.hashCode(row);
        }

        @Override
        public boolean equals(Object obj) {
            if (this == obj)
                return true;
            if (obj == null)
                return false;
            if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
                return false;
            Element other = (Element) obj;
            return Arrays.deepEquals(this.row, other.row);
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return Arrays.toString(row);
        }
    }
}
```